# Accessing django model attribute passed as a parameter

Tags: django

I'm using django with a legacy database where I can not change the original table columns. I have similar models which have slightly varying field names. The following model is an example.

```
class EURegister(models.Model):
    record_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
```

In some models, `reg_no` is a different name such as `registration_id`. Hence, I have to access the model attribute passed as an argument. But I can not use it since the model doesn't allow to use attributes as they were `dict` keys. It gives the following error.

```
TypeError: 'EURegister' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [**`getattr(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(myeuregister, 'reg_no')
```

So `getattr(x, 'y')` is equivalent to `x.y`.

That being said, if different models are (very) similar, it might make more sense to "merge" these models in a single model. Using different tables for the same types of objects is often not very good design.